# GCP Project quota error while linking projects to billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Am getting this error while linking my-project to billing account, i am not sure if there is any document available that says projects have limitations

```
(gcloud.beta.billing.projects.link) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure
  violations:
  - description: 'Cloud billing quota exceeded: https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase'
```

Pls suggest

I enabled the APIS , again bit confusing first enabled  alpha and then beta, then executed below cmdlet

`gcloud beta  billing projects link my-project --billing-account xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx`

as per the [GCP Doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/billing)

Comment: You have a quota problem. How many projects are linked to the billing account? What is **your** quota? If you are at the limit request a quota increase: https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase

Comment: Hi John,  i can see 6 projects   in my account, i am not sure how do i check my quota , the document explain a lot about quota and limitations  but does not explicitly says anything about projects and the billing account related figures,

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console web GUI. In the search box type `quota`. Google also provides documentation on how to look up and manage quotas. However, we cannot help you with quotas. That is enforced by Google Cloud. Limit the number of projects to your quota limit. You can request an upgrade, but you must have a good reason why you need more than six.

Comment: Thanks John,  The "projects linked to Billing Account"  are 3 Projects,  as long as my payment details are available,Platform should provide N numbers of Projects or at least some good number,

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 3 projects max, i had 6 projects and i was not sure unless i hit the project quota limit, the number of projects allowed link to a billing accounts is 3. you can request additional quota through GCP portal/console.
However its bit confusing regarding the linked billing account.i had tried to enable billing & linking to account through sdk using my billing account user but i was unable to do,

as per GCP `You have 21 projects remaining in your quota. Request an increase or delete projects. [Learn more][1]`

If you happen to find documentation which has clear instructions, feel free to comment and i can modify the answer